# SQL like operator on each row of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Table1**

| Short name |
| --- |
| KA |
| ERCA |
| MES |
| RNES |

**Table2**

| CustomerName |
| --- |
| Wilman Kala |
| Tradição Hipermerca |
| Hanari Carnes |
| Victuailles en stoc |
| Suprêmes délices |
| Hanari Carnes |

Now I want to fetch all the values from Table 2 by verifying individual row

EX :

```
select * from Table2 where CustomerName like '%KA%' 
UNION 
select * from Table2 where CustomerName like '%ERCA%'
UNION 
select * from Table2 where CustomerName like '%MES%'
```

and so on...  I am having 16000 + rows in Table1

Comment: not clear question! do you have 2 different table or only one? If you have 2 tables what is the relataion between them? If you have one table, why do not you show us together?

Comment: what have you tried till now and where are you facing the problem?

Comment: `LIKE '%' + col1 + '%'` should do the trick

Comment: I had update the Question @Akshay Gaonkar

Comment: join both the table with the condition `ON Table2.CustomerName LIKE '%' + Table1.[Short name]+ '%'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` in combination with `like`

```
select * 
from t2
where exists (
  select * from t1
  where t2.customername like '%' + t1.shortname + '%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to join both tables and check if they match the `like`.

```
declare @keys table (col1 varchar(20))
insert into @keys (col1)
       values ('KA'), 
              ('ERCA'), 
              ('MES'), 
              ('RNES')

declare @Table2 table (CustomerName varchar(100))
insert into @Table2 (CustomerName)
       values ('Wilman Kala'),
              ('Tradição Hipermerca'),
              ('Hanari Carnes'),
              ('Victuailles en stoc'),
              ('Suprêmes délices'),
              ('Hanari Carnes')
              
select col1, CustomerName
from @keys              
     inner join @Table2 on CustomerName like '%' + col1 + '%'
```

Result:

| col1 | CustomerName |
| --- | --- |
| KA | Wilman Kala |
| ERCA | Tradição Hipermerca |
| MES | Suprêmes délices |
| RNES | Hanari Carnes |
| RNES | Hanari Carnes |

Here you can see it running [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a68c7c236e62ebbedb462529aeae6172)

Notice that `Hanari Carnes` appears twice in the result, because it exists twice in `Table2`. If you want it to appear only once, you have to use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

**PS**: You have updated your question. To get the result of your new example you have to return only `CustomerName` in combination with `DISTINCT`.

```
select distinct CustomerName
from @keys              
     inner join @Table2 on CustomerName like '%' + col1 + '%'
```

| CustomerName |
| --- |
| Wilman Kala |
| Tradição Hipermerca |
| Suprêmes délices |
| Hanari Carnes |

[Fiddle link for updated question](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=44482112683a8de28b59be1b2ba20917)